Do we use deduction in everyday life?
Do we - normal people not logicians etc. - use deduction in everyday life? I took a class that talked about the psychology of deductive reasoning, and don't recall much of it beyond how most people don't use it correctly. I am asking because I wondered whether someone claiming to have deduced something about life is just being philosophical. I think it can be contrasted with ampliative reasoning, in which we go beyond what the premises. I am especially interested in whether we can reason about our social world deductively. I can google it

Social cognitive inferences are typically varieties of diagnostic
reasoning or, more properly, “abductive” reasoning, in which people
infer simple but plausible—although not deductively certain—underlying
causes for observable social behaviors.

